# SQL não retorna todos os resultados

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

Tenho 2 tabelas no MySQL, uma chamada **municipios** e outra chamada **municipios_ibge** ambas tem uma coluna chamada **municipio** que guarda o município de cada cidade do Brasil. Eu tenho que fazer o seguinte: Preciso verificar se os municípios da tabela **municipios_ibge** tem na tabela **municipios** e caso tenha, listar ele então na tela.

Atualmente ao invez de listar o nome do município eu estou listando o mesmo comando utilizando para fazer o `WHERE`pois nas tabelas tem mais de 5 mil registros e ele me retorna pouco menos de 20 registros na tela sendo que no banco pelo menos 70% dos dados são iguais de ambas tabelas.

Quando faço o comando `SELECT * FROM municipios WHERE municipio LIKE '%Alto Alegre%'`no phpmyadmin ele me retorna dados, mas quando o script que to usando faz ele não retorna nada.

Meu código

```
<?php

$estados_list = array("AC"=>"Acre", "AL"=>"Alagoas", "AM"=>"Amazonas", "AP"=>"Amapá","BA"=>"Bahia","CE"=>"Ceará","DF"=>"Distrito Federal","ES"=>"Espírito Santo","GO"=>"Goiás","MA"=>"Maranhão","MT"=>"Mato Grosso","MS"=>"Mato Grosso do Sul","MG"=>"Minas Gerais","PA"=>"Pará","PB"=>"Paraíba","PR"=>"Paraná","PE"=>"Pernambuco","PI"=>"Piauí","RJ"=>"Rio de Janeiro","RN"=>"Rio Grande do Norte","RO"=>"Rondônia","RS"=>"Rio Grande do Sul","RR"=>"Roraima","SC"=>"Santa Catarina","SE"=>"Sergipe","SP"=>"São Paulo","TO"=>"Tocantins");

$conexao = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=alb', 'root', 'root', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

$municipios_ibge = $conexao->query("SELECT * FROM municipios_ibge ORDER BY municipio");

while($dados = $municipios_ibge->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

  $municipio = trim($dados['municipio']);

  $municipios = $conexao->query("SELECT * FROM `municipios` WHERE TRIM(`municipio`) LIKE '%$municipio%' ORDER BY `municipio` ASC");

  if($municipios->rowCount() > 0){

    echo "SELECT * FROM `municipios` WHERE TRIM(`municipio`) LIKE '%$municipio%' ORDER BY `municipio` ASC".'<br />';
  }
}


?>
```

O que ele retorna:

```
SELECT * FROM `municipios` WHERE TRIM(`municipio`) LIKE '%Agronômica%' ORDER BY `municipio` ASC
SELECT * FROM `municipios` WHERE TRIM(`municipio`) LIKE '%Alto Bela Vista%' ORDER BY `municipio` ASC
SELECT * FROM `municipios` WHERE TRIM(`municipio`) LIKE '%Anita Garibaldi%' ORDER BY `municipio` ASC
SELECT * FROM `municipios` WHERE TRIM(`municipio`) LIKE '%Arabutã%' ORDER BY `municipio` ASC
SELECT * FROM `municipios` WHERE TRIM(`municipio`) LIKE '%Arroio Trinta%' ORDER BY `municipio` ASC
SELECT * FROM `municipios` WHERE TRIM(`municipio`) LIKE '%Arvoredo%' ORDER BY `municipio` ASC
SELECT * FROM `municipios` WHERE TRIM(`municipio`) LIKE '%Atalanta%' ORDER BY `municipio` ASC
SELECT * FROM `municipios` WHERE TRIM(`municipio`) LIKE '%Aurora%' ORDER BY `municipio` ASC
SELECT * FROM `municipios` WHERE TRIM(`municipio`) LIKE '%Bandeirante%' ORDER BY `municipio` ASC
SELECT * FROM `municipios` WHERE TRIM(`municipio`) LIKE '%Barra Bonita%' ORDER BY `municipio` ASC
SELECT * FROM `municipios` WHERE TRIM(`municipio`) LIKE '%Capão Alto%' ORDER BY `municipio` ASC
SELECT * FROM `municipios` WHERE TRIM(`municipio`) LIKE '%Chapadão do Lageado%' ORDER BY `municipio` ASC
SELECT * FROM `municipios` WHERE TRIM(`municipio`) LIKE '%Cordilheira Alta%' ORDER BY `municipio` ASC
SELECT * FROM `municipios` WHERE TRIM(`municipio`) LIKE '%Cunhataí%' ORDER BY `municipio` ASC
SELECT * FROM `municipios` WHERE TRIM(`municipio`) LIKE '%Dona Emma%' ORDER BY `municipio` ASC
SELECT * FROM `municipios` WHERE TRIM(`municipio`) LIKE '%Formosa do Sul%' ORDER BY `municipio` ASC
SELECT * FROM `municipios` WHERE TRIM(`municipio`) LIKE '%Forquilhinha%' ORDER BY `municipio` ASC
SELECT * FROM `municipios` WHERE TRIM(`municipio`) LIKE '%Fraiburgo%' ORDER BY `municipio` ASC
```

Ele me retorna somente esses dados de uma tabela que tem mais de 5 mil registros sendo que pelo menos 4 mil são iguais de ambas tabelas.

Comment: Dá um count(); na variável: $municipios_ibge para ver quantos registros ele ta trazendo nessa primeira consulta.

Comment: @KayoBruno ele retorna 5732

Comment: Volta e meia esses problemas de fucnionar no phpmyadmin e não no PHP aparecem, tente substituir seu ` `, por aspas simples ou duplas, a única operação que uso o sinal grave é nas inserções, as demais são aspas simples, pelo menos nos meus programas funcionam

Comment: Tem duas coisas que não entendi , para que você usar o lista $estados_list ?  e para que você usar o TRIM em TRIM(`municipio`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente altera sua query para que ele veja o que existe na outra tabela em vez de fazer esses loops sem necessidades.

```
SELECT * FROM municipios M
 WHERE  exists ( 
                SELECT * FROM municipios_ibge Mibge
                where  Mibge.municipio like M.municipio
                )
ORDER BY municipio ASC
```

> Obs; Para usar o Like com uma coluna de outra tabela é necessário o
>   uso da função CONCAT();

```
SELECT * FROM @municipios M
 WHERE  exists ( 
                SELECT * FROM @municipios_ibge Mibge
                where  Mibge.municipio LIKE CONCAT('%', M.municipio, '%') 
                )
ORDER BY municipio ASC
```